# Run section of puppet manifest once a day but with hourly poll

Tags: puppet

I have nodes checking into a puppet server every hour.

We have some tasks which we want to run on check-in but only once a day.

Would it be possible to make a function inside a puppet manifest that saves last run time and only runs if the last time was over 24 hours?

**Update:**

I did try one thing which semi-works. That is move the chunk of puppet code into a separate file, and have my main puppet ensure a cron job exists for it.

The complaint I go back from another department with this is that they can no longer see install errors on puppet board. This image shows 2 nodes on the old puppet branch and 1 on the new branch:

[image]

With having `cron` run `puppet apply myFile.pp` we no longer got the feedback from failures on Puppetboard, as the main script simply ensures that the cron job exists:

Answer (score 3):

You have at least two options.

Assuming your unspecified task is handled by an exec resource, you could design this in such a way that Puppet only ever regards the exec as out of sync once per day. That could be achieved by having your exec write the calendar day into a file. Then you could add an `unless` attribute:

```
unless => "test $(</var/tmp/last_run) == $(date +%d)"
```

Obviously your exec would need to also keep track of updating that file.

A second option would be to use the schedule metaparameter:

```
schedule { 'everyday':
  period => daily,
  range  => '1:00 - 1:59',
}

exec { 'do your thing':
  schedule => 'everyday',
}
```

That assumes that Puppet really will run only once per hour. The risk of course is that Puppet runs more than once in that hour, e.g. a sysadmin might manually run it.

Comment: Thanks interesting solution would you get feedback on the puppet system if the script returned an error? I updated my question with something similar I tried and the complaint I got back from another department.

Comment: One might also consider using [`repeat => 1`](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/types/schedule.html#schedule-attribute-repeat) in the `Schedule` instead of a `range`.  Or in addition to a `range`.